# Handling click events with jquery in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, event-handling

I'm trying to add an event handler in Google Chrome to handle click events using jquery. Here is code from modal.php:

```
<script>
    $('.event-sel').on('click', function(event){
        console.log('handling event selection');
    });
</script>

<form>
    <select>
        <option class=".event-sel">This is an option</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This code is meant to handle click events for all items of a particular css class. The above code works fine in Firefox. Why doesn't this work in Google Chrome?

The above code is used in a modal dialog window.

Comment: What's the code at `// do something`?

Comment: [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/spyz1gwq) - tested in Chrome latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for clicks on the `select` element, not the `option` element. You want something more like this:

```
<form>
    <select class="event-sel">
        <option>This is an option</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    $('.event-sel').on('click', function(event){
        console.log('handling event selection');
    });
</script>
```

Here it is in a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mbdfk89/8/

Hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: I made update above, the actual css class is .event-sel. The code I replaced with do something is currently: console.log('handling event selection');

Comment: Set up a Fiddle or something showing it not working in Chrome. This totally works for me and probably hundreds of thousands of other people who have used jQuery to add click handlers for Chrome users. So something is weird somewhere that is not evident in the three lines in your question.

Comment: I've added a few more guesses/possibilities/things to check in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible that Google Chrome will not let me bind event handlers between <script></script> tags? I am now testing my code on the index page and it still does not work...

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to handle the click on the select element, not the option element. I've edited my answer with a solution that hopefully works for you.

Comment: Handling click event for 'select' element fixed the problem.  I should be handling 'change' events for 'select' tag.